# Python scrapy spider crawl all sub-sites of different urls

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

please excuse me if I'm just being stupid bc I'm fairly new to Python and Webscraping

I want to scrape all text elements of multiple sites with different structures and therefore in a first step want to crawl over each site and retrieve all urls of the different sub-sites for each domain

But first of all my code doesn't work for every link I pass, I get this notification

> 2020-09-29 17:24:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://markus-pieper.eu/>](https://markus-pieper.eu/%3E) (referer: None)

And finally how can I restart the process once it is done for one link? My idea was to do it for every link in a for loop so I get a list of sub-site urls for every link but I can't restart the crawler with a new url

Can someone help? Thanks so much in advance

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import re

global base_links, link_list, links
link_list = []
base_links = []

# assign list of urls to crawl
links = ['https://bernd-lange.de/',
         'https://markus-pieper.eu/']

# strips urls in order to get base-urls
for link in links:
    base = re.sub('/$', '', link)
    base = re.sub('^https:\/\/', '', base)
    base = re.sub('^www.', '', base)
    base_links.append(base)


class SpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name= "sites"
    #allowed_domains = base_links

    le = LinkExtractor(allow_domains = base_links, unique=True)

    #rules = [Rule(le, callback='parse_all_subsites', follow=True)]
    rules = [Rule(le, callback='parse_all_subsites', follow=False)]

    def parse_all_subsites(self, response):
        #for link in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
        extracted_links = self.le.extract_links(response)
        pages = set()

        for link in extracted_links:
            pages.add(link.url)

        link_list.append(pages)


process = CrawlerProcess()

#iterates over every link and adds list of links of every sub-site to link_list
for link in links:

    process.crawl(SpiderSpider, start_urls=link)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
2020-09-29 17:24:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://markus-pieper.eu/> (referer: None)
```

This is a DEBUG message, it's telling you the engine crawled that url, nothing else. It's not an error. If you don't want to see DEBUG messages you can set your `LOG_LEVEL` to `'INFO'` (or any other level you want) in the `settings.py`. [Read more.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=log_level#log-level)

---

I don't understand what's the point of this part of your code:

```
global base_links, link_list, links
link_list = []
base_links = []

# assign list of urls to crawl
links = ['https://bernd-lange.de/',
         'https://markus-pieper.eu/']

# strips urls in order to get base-urls
for link in links:
    base = re.sub('/$', '', link)
    base = re.sub('^https:\/\/', '', base)
    base = re.sub('^www.', '', base)
    base_links.append(base)
```

It seems you can replace all of this with:

```
 class SpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
     start_urls = ['https://bernd-lange.de/',
                   'https://markus-pieper.eu/']
```

If I'm mistaken, please explain what you are trying to do here.

---

Finally, I think `CrawlerProcess` isn't really meant for use inside a loop [like that]. When you call `process.start()` Scrapy's CrawlerProcess will start a Twisted reactor that by default will stop when the crawlers are finished and it doesn't expect to be restarted.

Particularly, I think you can do all you want in the same spider with the same process, just using all your links in the `start_urls` attribute. Anyway, if you want/need to keep this design, you can check in the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) there are an example of running multiple spiders in the same process. Another possible solution you can try is calling `process.start()` with the `stop_after_crawl=False`, read more [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.start).